# Discord.js: TypeError: message.guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size; is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to code a bot to get the number of people in a specific role in the discord server.
here is my code line:

```
client.on('message', message =>{

    let roleID = "786148346846117940";
    let memberCount = message.guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
});
```

But the console shows error:

```
C:\Users\admin\OneDrive - aaaxaa\Desktop\Discord_Bot\main.js:27
    let memberCount = message.guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
                                          ^
TypeError: message.guild.roles.get is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

From discord.js V12 you need to use cache property like this

```
let roleID = "786148346846117940";
let memberCount = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members.size;
```

Comment: I tried it but it messed up the results. Even when 1 user had the role it showed me 0 as the answer but when i was the user who had the role its showed me 1 but when someone else had the role it showed as 0. How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: I did this, and I got an error for `cache` being undefined, and since `cache` was undefined so was `get()`.